# How to install ASITIC (Simulation of Spiral Inductors and Transformers) CAD tool?

Tags: linux, cygwin, 32-bit

I want to run ASITIC [http://rfic.eecs.berkeley.edu/~niknejad/download.html](http://rfic.eecs.berkeley.edu/%7Eniknejad/download.html)
But it was developed upon an old architechture and g77 compliler as far i know and while i used this app on Ubuntu I had to add foreign architecture i386.

Due to some issues i have been facing i removed foreign architecture and uninstalled the software(ASITIC). I had planned to install it in Cygwin(in Windows 10) (as it was recommended back in 2004 (website mentioned)). I downloaded files (Intel Linux Pentium 4 (updated 1/6/04) & The common files (all platforms).) and then extracted it into a folder and moved there in Cygwin extracted and made the "asitic_linux" executable(using chmod +x asitic_linux) and then it executed giving me error

```
./asitic_linux: cannot execute binary file: Exec format error
```

I tried to check file prerequisites using "file asitic_linux" command output was as follows

```
asitic_linux: ELF 32-bit LSB executable, Intel 80386, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked, interpreter /lib/ld-linux.so.2, for GNU/Linux 2.2.5, stripped, too many notes (256)
```

I know there are mainly 2 issues one is i have to install architecture and the other is required libraries.

**Any idea how i can install foreign architecture to run the given application in Cygwin**

I also found a new information that Cygwin does not support ELF executable binaries. Thats why on running ldd asitic_linux it gives following error.

```
ldd: asitic_linux: Exec format error
```

I will try running the software in WLS(Windows Subsystem For Linux) and let know more.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Preparation/Prerequisite - what you will need is:

#Compiler for c(gcc) & c++(g++)(our binary depends on many libraries of these compilers) use command

`sudo apt build-essential`

(dont type wrong spelling eg: essentials or essensial, just use tab key to autocomplete name)

#i386 architecture

`dpkg --add-architecture i386`

#Cross-compiling functionality - install gcc-multilib

`sudo apt install gcc-multilib`)(most important)

Then,

`sudo apt update&&sudo apt upgrade`

Then, I downloaded asitic_linux (`wget http://rfic.eecs.berkeley.edu/~niknejad/Asitic/grackle/asitic_linux.gz`) and extracted it(`gzip -d asitic_linux.gz`) it gave me binary asitic_linux, which i converted into executable with following command

`chmod +x asitic_linux`

Then I found the name of dependencies(list of libraries it depends) using following command

`ldd asitic_linux`

[image: this is output]

DOWNLOAD Packages[choose:i386] From Link Provided Below

https://packages.debian.org/bullseye/libxext6 [libXext.so.6]

https://packages.debian.org/bullseye/libx11-6 [libX11.so.6]

https://packages.debian.org/bullseye/libxcb1 [libxcb.so.1]

https://packages.debian.org/bullseye/libxau6 [libXau.so.6]

https://packages.debian.org/bullseye/libxdmcp6 [libXdmcp.so.6]

https://packages.debian.org/bullseye/libbsd0 [libbsd.so.0]

https://packages.debian.org/bullseye/libmd0 [libmd.so.0]

http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/g/gcc-3.4/libg2c0_3.4.6-6ubuntu5_i386.deb [libg2c]

Then, EXTRACT

You can also use file manager itself to extract it

> For example after downloading
> libxext.so.6(libxext6_1.3.4-1build1_i386), i extract the
> libxext6_1.3.4-1build1_i386.deb file then extract the data.tar.zst
> file present inside that which gave me two files "libXext.so.6 &
> libXext.so.6.4.0"

Make a folder to collect all extracted files
[image: custom_libs]

**Alternatively you can download all of the above binaries at one place from my drive** https://mega.nz/folder/di4C1K4I#XC74pOD51CsOOKaTGdO5rg

Open terminal in same folder: mouse right click>>"Open in Terminal", then use `pwd` to know the exact location of path `Ctrl+C`copy it for pasting later in shell with `Ctrl+Shift+V`

Now use following command to set environment variables

`echo 'export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:exact/path/to/folder' >> ~/.bashrc`

Now you can run `./asitic_linux` (or sudo ./asitic_linux)

[image: ASITIC RUNNING]

Comment: Someone asked me about how to install ASITIC on CentOS7 (which is based on Red Hat unlike Ubuntu which is based on Debian). I am Sorry that I couldn't help with CentOS but many command line functions like `chmod +x asitic_linux` `ldd asitic_linux` and  `echo 'export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:exact/path/to/folder' >> ~/.bashrc`  would work in CentOS as well. Also CentOS has no multiarch support hence I find it difficult to find a method of running this 32 BIT Binary Software(i386 architecture) if the host system is 64 Bit(amd64 architecture). Try and let me know about progress.

Answer (score 0):

If you read the documentation you will notice that the original autor is providing only binary versions that are 19 years old.
As he is NOT providing the source code there is NO way that you can install it in a current system: nor Cygwin neither Linux.

All systems evolved, shared libraries changed but as this program was never shared as source version, porting is not possible.

Comment: I've used the software earlier on Ubuntu after Installing Foreign Architecture i386 and related libraries and some extra libraries